# Copy/Pasting page source doesn't recreate same webpage. Why not?

Tags: html

Just as an experiment - I have taken the page source from a webpage I am viewing and copied it into a file on my desktop. When I try to open this file in my browser, I get a jumbled mess with no formatting.

What could the original page have that my copy does not?

Comment: Use the browser developer tools (f12) and its network tab to see what resources are not being loaded.

Comment: That's because you are not adding the css file which defines the formatting, alignment and style of the webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're missing the stylesheets as well. Stylesheets include the styling (formatting) for the html.

Comment: Ahh fair enough. So the stylesheets exist somewhere on the server where the original page can reference them then.

Comment: It depends on how they did it. I, for example, load my styles through javascript files so it's hard to say.

Comment: With your method, wouldn't you be able to see the css when viewing the page's source?

Comment: You could inspect the web page and click on the sources tab and dig down and find it. I use React and webpack bundles and compiles the javascript. You couldn't just copy and paste it all and make it work. It has a lot more moving parts.

Answer (score 2):

Copying the files from original site through `Viewsourcepage`, you will not get the `CSS` and `JavaScript` files. Usually we call `CSS` and `JavaScript` from external source so that is the thing you are facing problem here

My best suggestion is if you want to copy the files from original website use [Httracker](https://www.httrack.com/page/2/). Download `httrack` from the website, Install it and use

Answer (score 1):

There are probably CSS and/or JS files that are loaded dynamically from where ever you copied the HTML from. But they are probably relative locations, and you didn't copy those files too.

Answer (score 1):

Static web pages will work when you do this. Their content do not change.

A lot of pages nowadays are dynamic and the source changes based on the client side JS code or values from the backend.

There could also be frameworks and a lot of dependancies for that particular page.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of copy/paste manually, you can try some `websitedownloader` eg. it's an online one https://websitedownloader.io/